# How to add an anchor text in Oracle Apex 5.0

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to create a login page where below the "Login" button I want to create a html text saying "Do not have an account? Click here to register." Here "Click here" will be an anchor text and when user clicks "Click here" it will redirect the user to the registration page.

I have searched for a whole day to achieve this but could not find any solution. I am new to oracle apex. Could anyone help me explaining the procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to create a Display As Text item with the source:

```
Do not have an account? <a href="f?p=whatever">Click here</a> to register.
```

Set Escape HTML to "No"so that the link is displayed properly.

Comment: where will I find display as text? I am sorry if this is a silly question. I am new to oracle apex.

Comment: There is a "Display Only" item in Page Designer. I changed the Label of this item to "Do not have an account? <a href="f?p=whatever">Click here</a> to register." 
In "whatever" I wrote 3.
Now "Click here" is showing as  link but cannot go to the 3rd page of when I click.

Comment: Okay. Finally I am able to achieve what I wanted.
1. I created a "Display Only" item in the page.
2. Then remove the Label.
3. In "Based On" section I selected "Output of PL/SQL Code".
4. Then as PL/SQL Code I entered the following code:
    BEGIN
   HTP.print ('<html>');
   HTP.print ('<body bgcolor=blue>');
   HTP.print ('Do not have an account? <a href="f?p=&APP_ID.:3:&SESSION.">Click here</a> to register.');
   HTP.print ('</body>');
   HTP.print ('</html>');
END;

5. And saved and run the page.

Comment: That's quite possibly the most awkward way to do it. You could have just copied the code and pasted in your region's footer.

Answer (score 2):

Create Static content sub region on Login region, choose style "Blank with attributes", just write HTML code: 
`<a href="f?p==&APP_ID.:"#PAGE_NUMBER#":&SESSION." title="Click to register!">Sign Up!</a>`

That's all.